# Livereload isn't working in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, livereload

I used gulp-webapp (generator from yeoman) and add some other tasks (like gulp-sass & gulp-coffee).

But now Livereload isn't starting. I need to see something like this

```
[gulp] Live reload server listening on: 35729
```

But output looks like

```
➜  app git:(master) ✗ gulp watch
[gulp] Using gulpfile ~/Dev/lsd/app/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'clean'...
[gulp] Starting 'styles'...
[gulp] Starting 'scripts'...
[gulp] Starting 'connect'...
[gulp] Finished 'connect' after 68 ms
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' after 181 ms
[gulp] gulp-size: total 128.75 kB
[gulp] Finished 'styles' after 806 ms
[gulp] Starting 'serve'...
[gulp] Finished 'serve' after 5.73 ms
```

And I don't understand, what is my problem.

My `gulpfile.coffee`:

```
"use strict"

gulp = require("gulp")
$ = require("gulp-load-plugins")()

gulp.task "styles", ->
  gulp.src("app/styles/main.scss").pipe($.sass()).pipe($.autoprefixer("last 1 version")).pipe(gulp.dest(".tmp/styles")).pipe $.size()

gulp.task "scripts", ->
  gulp.src("app/scripts/**/*.coffee").pipe($.coffee()).pipe gulp.dest(".tmp/scripts")

gulp.task "html", [
  "styles"
  "scripts"
], ->
  jsFilter = $.filter("**/*.js")
  cssFilter = $.filter("**/*.css")
  gulp.src("app/*.html").pipe($.useref.assets()).pipe(jsFilter).pipe($.uglify()).pipe(jsFilter.restore()).pipe(cssFilter).pipe($.csso()).pipe(cssFilter.restore()).pipe($.useref.restore()).pipe($.useref()).pipe(gulp.dest("dist")).pipe $.size()

gulp.task "clean", ->
  gulp.src([
    ".tmp"
    "dist"
  ],
    read: false
  ).pipe $.clean()

gulp.task "build", [
  "html"
  "fonts"
]
gulp.task "default", ["clean"], ->
  gulp.start "build"

gulp.task "connect", ->
  connect = require("connect")
  app = connect().use(require("connect-livereload")(port: 35729)).use(connect.static("app")).use(connect.static(".tmp")).use(connect.directory("app"))
  require("http").createServer(app).listen(9000).on "listening", ->
    console.log "Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000"

gulp.task "serve", [
  "styles"
  "scripts"
  "connect"
], ->
  require("opn") "http://localhost:9000"

gulp.task "watch", [
  "clean"
  "serve"
], ->
  server = $.livereload()
  gulp.watch([
    "app/*.html"
    ".tmp/styles/**/*.css"
    ".tmp/scripts/**/*.js"
  ]).on "change", (file) ->
    server.changed file.path

  gulp.watch "app/styles/**/*.scss", ["styles"]
  gulp.watch "app/scripts/**/*.coffee", ["scripts"]
```

Comment: I am having the same problem when depend watch on task containing livereload call.

Comment: Just an FYI. You can break the lines so each pipe is on it's own line and indented. Might lose your sanity otherwise.

Comment: Here is a clean up version: https://gist.github.com/sukima/b5a2d145a1b34dece7f9

Comment: Also is `require("opn")` correct?

Comment: So just curious, have anybody tried my answer. Because I know it works. I'm using it right now. check it out my working [server](https://github.com/markuz-gj/etc-etc/blob/master/server.js) file

Comment: You can try "Live Reload Browser Page" https://github.com/Yuriy-Svetlov/live-reload-bp  or website https://live-reload-browser-page.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [gulp-webserver](https://github.com/schickling/gulp-webserver). It makes using LiveReload very simple.

```
gulp = require 'gulp'
webserver = 'gulp-webserver'
path = 'path'

gulp.task "webserver", ->
    gulp.src(path.resolve("./dist")).pipe webserver(
        port: "8080"
        livereload: true
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I use gulp and with livereload and they are all working great.
take a look [here](https://github.com/markuz-gj/etc-etc/blob/master/server.js). 
This is a server task I use for dev purpose. It is fully working.

This snipped **has being tested**

```
http = require "http"
path = require "path"
Promise = Promise or require("es6-promise").Promise
express = require "express"
gulp = require "gulp"
{log} = require("gulp-util")
tinylr = require "tiny-lr"
livereload = require "gulp-livereload"

ROOT = "dist"
GLOBS = [path.join(ROOT, "/**/*")]
PORT = 8000
PORT_LR = PORT + 1

app = express()
app.use require("connect-livereload") {port: PORT_LR}
app.use "/", express.static "./dist"

http.createServer(app).listen PORT, ->
  log "Started express server on http://localhost: #{PORT}"

lrUp = new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
  lrServer = tinylr()
  lrServer.listen PORT_LR, (err) ->
    return reject(err)  if err
    resolve lrServer

gulp.watch GLOBS, (evt) ->
  return if evt.type is "deleted"

  lrUp.then (lrServer) ->
    log "LR: reloading", path.relative(ROOT, evt.path)
    gulp.src(evt.path).pipe livereload(lrServer)
```

Note I'm using a different port for livereload (9001), I do this because often you want to have multiple instance of the livereload server running in parallel.
The suggestion to use port 35729 is only if you are using a browser extension, which you aren't since you are using the connect middleware.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Live reload is very easy to using gulp and express the code is below

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
gulp.task('express', function() {   
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();   
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 4002}));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));   
  app.listen(4000); 
});


var tinylr; 
gulp.task('livereload', function() {   
 tinylr = require('tiny-lr')();   
 tinylr.listen(4002); 
});


function notifyLiveReload(event) {   
 var fileName = require('path').relative(__dirname, event.path);   
 tinylr.changed({
        body: {
          files: [fileName]
        }  
    });
}

gulp.task('watch', function() {  
  gulp.watch('*.html', notifyLiveReload);  
  gulp.watch('js/*.js', notifyLiveReload);    
  gulp.watch('css/*.css', notifyLiveReload); 
});

gulp.task('default', ['express', 'livereload', 'watch'], function() {

});
```

when you are change the html,js and css file it will reload

Answer (score 0):

I originally suggested changing the port however livereload doesnt prefer this as an option. What you need to do is kill the service running on port 35729, you do this by running the following command from the terminal:

```
lsof -iTCP:35729
```

This will then give you a list of proccesses running on this port, pick the first PID in the list i.e. 3996 then run this command:

```
 kill -9 3996
```

Now start your gulp script again and it wont conflict.